# Points to keep while developing acadamic progress tracking system

Tags: asp.net, web-applications, analytics

Hi I am developing a **student progress tracking system**, where I need to show the weak points in particular subject as well the strong point in the subject. I need to deliver the analytical data on students academic performance so what should I keep in mind while developing such **web-application**? I need to emphasis more on analytic data so any help on that?

Comment: not sure what others think but I for one think that this question would have received an appropriate answer if there had been a meeting with the client to discuss "use cases", as well as more details around how you would present the data, with that information a better perspective of what would need to be done would be achieved in which there could be an discussion (if there are more developers) of what tools, patterns and so on to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Talk a little more about the data and how it's used:
1) How much data will you need to store?
2) How often will it be loaded?
3) How many users will be pulling this data at any given time?
4) Will the data ever be modified?

Depending on your answer, you'll get different suggestions.  Ultimately, if you're just doing single-row inserts and the data size is low, then MySQL with a front-end reporting tool (Jaspersoft/Pentaho/BIRT work great) would work well.  If you're wanting a solid analytic database and the data size is bigger, then Infobright with those reporting tools works great too.

If you're doing a cross, then it's common to use both databases (one for transactions and then moved to analytic db for the analytic front end).  If that data size is quite low, though, you won't see much of a difference going between analytic or transactional databases.

As for front end BI tools, you can use Jaspersoft/Pentaho/Actuate(BIRT) for out-of-the-box, open-source solutions.  If you'd like to create your own, I'd recommend Zend Framework (PHP) to get your app developed.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks, it has given me a strong vision for my back-end, any suggestion on MSSQL + ASP.NET for reporting?